# How to uniformly detect an integer’s sign bit across various encodings (1's complement, 2's complement, sign magnitude)?

Tags: c, history, twos-complement

**How to detect an `int` sign-ness in C?**

This question is mostly of historical machines. What I am asking how to distinguish if an integer is 0 or -0. In 1's complement and sign/magnitude int encoding, both a 0 (or +0) and -0 are possible.

---

The simple sign bit test is to compare against `0`.

```
int x;
printf("sign bit is %s\n", (x < 0) ? "set" : "not set");
```

But this fails in 1's complement and sign magnitude when `x` is `-0`.

---

1st Candidate approach: Mask test.
As C defines that an `int` must have a sign bit regardless of integer encoding, the following should work.

```
int x;
int SignBitMask = tbd;
printf("sign bit is %s\n", (x & SignBitMask) ? "set" : "not set");
```

The question becomes how to determine the value of `SignBitMask` in C?
`SignBitMask = INT_MAX + 1` seems like a starting point.

---

2nd Candidate approach: create function and check bit patterns:

```
int IsSignBitSet(int x) {
  if (x > 0) return 0;
  if (x < 0) return 1;
  int zp = 0;
  if (memcmp(&x, &zp, sizeof x) == 0) return 0;
  int zn = -0;  // Is this even the way to form a -0?
  if (memcmp(&x, &zn, sizeof x) == 0) return 1;
  // If we get here, now what?
  return ?;
}
```

---

I'm thinking there is no portable uniform solution - maybe because the need no longer exists.

Why: I have wondered how various signed zeros were detected and printed.

Note: I have purposely avoided the "C" tag here and thought I'd try just the "History" tag first.

---

[Edit] Answer

Combining info of 3 answers and C11dr 6.2.6.2 "Integer types" (for `int`, a single sign bit *must* exist, the positive sign bit is 0, the negative sign bit is 1), a solution (that appears independent of 1's complement, 2's complement and sign/magnitude integer encoding) is

```
int IsSignBitSet_Best(int x) {
  // return 1 if x is less than 0 _or_ x is arithmetically 0 with some bit set.
  return (x < 0) || ((x == 0) && (* ((unsigned int*) &x) ));
}
```

The direct mask approach is simplest, but have not come up with a highly portable mask definition

```
int IsSignBitSet_Simple(int x) {
  static unsigned SignBitMask = 0x80;  // Or some other platform dependent mask
  return ((unsigned)x & SignBitMask) != 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions are likely to not get seen by many people if you only include a minor tag like [tag:history] (which might even need to be burninated).

Comment: The "sign bit" in C is the first bit (MSB) for all of these representations. -0 is counted as negative.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil My compliment on your complement edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find negative 0's just check for a zero with any bit at all set.

```
int testForNegative0(int x) { 
   return (x==0 && *((unsigned int*)&x)); 
}
```

Or to answer the question in the title:

```
int hasSignBitSet(int x) { 
   return (x<0) || testForNegative0(x);
}
```

This works for the 3 encodings you mention, it may not work for even more esoteric ones.

Comment: Very direct approach.  Please comment on if you know if this method was used BITD (back-in-the-day) when such non-2's compliment integer encoding were active.

Comment: Does `-0 == 0` in one's complement C?

Comment: @ribond, according to [wikipedia, yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement)

Comment: @rlbond one's complement zeros (0 or -0) behave _arithmetically_ the same.  So `-0 == 0` is true.  This is much the same as floating point numbers `-0.0 == 0.0` evaluates to true.  But I'll research the C spec.

Comment: @rlbond C11dr 6.2.6.2 does discuss negative 0.  I do not see yet a direct statement supporting my "-0 behaves arithmetically same as 0", but I think it is implied.

Comment: @chux: Integer arithmetic is defined in terms of value, not representation, so -0 and 0 must behave identically in that all arithmetic with them must produce identical values. (Arithmetic need not produce identical representations; -0+0 and 0+0 may give different representations of the same value, zero.) Note that the bitwise operators are defined in terms of bits; they are not arithmetic operations.

Comment: @chux, probably not.  For of all three of these encodings the msb determines the negative sign, so the print routine can just check that bit to decide when to print a leading `-`.  I'd guess they didn't try to attempt a cross-platform portable determination, they just used a mask based on the word size.

Comment: A corollary of the fact that arithmetic is defined by value is that distinguishing representations of zero requires non-arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are asking.  If you asking 'How do we determine if a machine is ones-complement, twos-complement, or sign-magnitude?' you can use:

```
if (1 & -1) {
    if (3 & -1 == 1)
        printf("sign magnitude\n");
    else
        printf("twos complement\n");
} else
    printf("ones complement\n");
```

Comment: Thank, but what I am asking how to distinguish if an integer is 0 or -0.  In 1's compliment and sign/magnitude `int` encoding, both a 0 (or +0) and -0 are possible.  Most machines these days are 2's compliment integers and a -0 does not occur.

Comment: I see that combining the comment suggested by @rlbond (in another answer) with this answer would provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. Do you know the encoding ahead of time? If not, what you are is asking is impossible, as the mappings are different for different encodings. For example,  the byte `1111111`, has a "sign" of 0 in one's complement but a sign of -1 in two's complement. So how can there be a universal way to check if they are defined differently?

EDIT: You might be able to cheat:

```
int sign(int x)
{
    if (x > 0) return 1;
    if (x > -1) return 0;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: There are various posts that show how one can, (see @Chris Dodd on this post) with some degree of portability, determine it the integer encoding is 2's compliment, 1's compliment, or sign-magnitude.  So if one did not know the encoding ahead of time, it could be discerned.

Comment: If that is what you are asking then you pretty much have your answer. Two's complement has only one zero, so that's easy to check. One's complement's zeros are `11111111` and `00000000`, and sign-magnitude's are `10000000` and `00000000`, so you can just check using a function that detects those specific numbers (of course, you'll have to adjust to the word length)

Comment: BTW "10000000, has a "sign" of 0 in one's complement ".  Is not _one's complement 10000000_ the value -127 (a thus a sign of 1)?

Comment: Oops, I meant "11111111".

Comment: BTW: Thanks for the tag update.  I would say _1111111 one's complement_ (-0) has a sign of 1 and an arithmetic value of 0.