# Are there any C implementations which have a useless single-bit `int` bitfield?

Tags: c, c99, bit-fields, c11

[6.7.2.1p9 of n1570](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p9) says:

> A member of a structure or union may have any complete object type other than a
>   variably modified type.123) In addition, a member may be declared to consist of a
>   specified number of bits (including a sign bit, if any). Such a member is called a
>   bit-field ;124) its width is preceded by a colon.

Do I understand correctly that this indicates that the single member in `struct { int bit:1; }` might be a sign bit?

If that's the case, then it follows that the only values such a bit-field might store on some implementations are `0` and `-0`, of which `-0` might be indistinguishable from `0` once stored or a trap representation.

Are there any actual implementations where only one value can be assigned to such a bit-field?

Comment: If there were such, it would be non-compliant. You can assign 0 to a 1-bit field, and you can assign either 1 or -1 to it. If it is signed, you'll read back -1.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker You are assuming twos complement signed integers... I should add that to the question, too, but if you know the spec then you'll know it's not necessary.

Comment: I would argue that `0` and `-0` are *not* "one value" as you describe.

Comment: @inetknght: whyever?

Comment: @inetknght Can you cite the C standard like I can?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Can you actually quote a stipulation in the standard with which the behaviour you describe (and which inetknght’s answer reproduces) does not comply?

Comment: @PJTraill "Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones' complement), is a trap representation or a normal value." -- http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p2

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: I’m confused: Is your quote from 6.2.6.2¶2 meant to explain why `0` and `-0` are not one value or cite a violated stipulation? If the former, are they not one value with two representations? Also, trap representations “need not represent a value of the object type”. But this sounds hairy: 6.2.6.1¶8, footnote 43: “Furthermore, `x == y` does not necessarily imply that `x` and `y` have the same value”.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: I’m getting the impression that the standard makes a distinction between the values of an object type and the values of an object; that an unqualified “value” is thus potentially ambiguous. In your question, when you say “only one value can be assigned to such a bit-field” you are presumably referring to values of the object type.

Comment: Given 2's complement, `bit = -1` is OK.

Comment: Minor: With non- 2's complement, `-0` is _distinguishable_ from `0` as they have different bit patterns - [detect an integer's sign bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869976/how-to-uniformly-detect-an-integer-s-sign-bit-across-various-encodings-1s-comp).  Not that it is easy to discern is a given value of `+0` or `-0`.

Comment: Apology: the footnote I cited 20 mins ago is 52 in C11, 43 in C99 (but apparently the same text).

Comment: @PJTraill Attempting to use a trap representation is UB, which is where the UB part of this question comes in.

Comment: @chux Yes of course, it *is* distinguishable by inspecting the bit pattern of the underlying object, *providing* the negative zero isn't converted to a regular 0... My bad. It also seems like the values `0` and negative zero *might* compare equal, or *might* compare unequal using regular comparison operators. That's left unspecified at the end of [6.2.6.2p3](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p3)...

Comment: @PJTraill ^--- That last comment might shed some light for you, too.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: It seems clear enough what is going on, but I feel that the term “value” is ambiguous unless qualified by “of the object” / “type”. Also it is sad (or is it a good thing?) that no-one has yet found a compiler using ones-complement for signed bit fields: we just have gcc and MSVS so far.

Comment: @PJTraill It is also possible for a twos complement trap representation to occur when the sign bit is 1 and all value bits are 0, as 6.2.6.2p2 says... though it seems *even less likely* that we'll find one of those!

Comment: @PJTraill I asked just now, ["Are there any implementations that support a negative zero, or reserve it as a trap representation?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586217/are-there-any-implementations-that-support-a-negative-zero-or-reserve-it-as-a-t)... So I guess we'll find that one out too :P

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: Unable to find spec support for +0, -0 "might compare unequal".  Please point that out  (I see it could fire a trap)

Comment: @chux ["It is unspecified whether these cases actually generate a negative zero or a normal zero, and whether a negative zero becomes a normal zero when stored in an object."](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p3) Keep in mind, this question *is about* storing it into an object.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour It is about the "might compare unequal"  that you commented.  Still find nothing to support -0 and +0 might compare unequal.

Comment: @chux You were asking for clarification, right? I gave clarification... What more do you want? Would you like me to change the question so that there are no objects involved, for the purpose of suiting your agenda? No... Since comments along this line aren't requesting further clarity for this question, I request that you cease...

Answer (score 5):

How about gcc 4.9.2?

```
/* gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror=all test.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct foo {
    int bit:1;
};

int main() {
    struct foo f;
    f.bit = 0;
    f.bit = 1;

    printf("%i\n", f.bit);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it emits:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror=all test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’: test.c:12:10: warning: overflow in
implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
  f.bit = 1;
          ^
```

Running it emits:

```
$ ./a.out 
-1
```

Comment: Hmm, this is an example of undefined behaviour due to signed integer overflow... Nice :)

Comment: Yet another reason that bitfields should almost always be avoided. They have surprising behavior in several areas and there's really little benefit that they provide. Even using dreaded and maligned pre-processor macros to set/get/clear bits is better than using bitfields (as long as the macros are written half-decently).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: No, it's an example of an implementation-defined result of a conversion. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.1.3 p3. Signed overflow on an arithmetic operator has undefined behavior; signed overflow on an integer-to-signed conversion yields an implementation-defined result (or raises an implementation-defined signal).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I wouldn't go that far. Bit-fields should almost always be explicitly unsigned -- and if you really want a signed bit-field, you should use `signed int`. (The type of a plain `int` bit-field is either `unsigned int` or `signed int`; the choice is implementation-defined. This the only case where plain `int` behaves this way.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Very well. There's still a slim chance that the implementation-defined signal could be one corresponding to computational exception, or that #6.2.6.2p3 might be in violation...

Comment: @KeithThompson: I agree with what you say - if you're going to use bitfields.  However, I think using bitfields is often the wrong choice (particularly for what people **want** to use them for: to model an external register/file/stream/data exchange format).

Comment: MSVS 2013 also accepts your code and displays -1 on stdout and in the debugger.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: IMHO, the proper way for the standard to accommodate bitfields would be to define a syntax to attach a name to specified bits *of other struct members*.  Such a design would not only allow code to use bitfields in a portable manner, but if bitfields could be assembled out of multiple components, would allow many other kinds of byte-assembling code to be written in portable fashion much more efficiently than is presently possible.

Comment: @supercat It seems to me like such an interface would penetrate into the implementation-defined (and possibly undefined) realms of signed integers and structs... Unless those problems are fixed, this wouldn't exactly be *portable*.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: Not really, if one specifies that the members have to be assembled out of bits taken from unsigned types, and must behave as two's-complement integers (even on platforms which use other forms of signed-integer math, using two's-complement form when storing and extracting bitfields would probably be more efficient than using other representations).  If one could specify that a struct contains two unsigned short, and that I want an alias to a signed integer comprisong bits 0..15 of the second at the bottom, and bits 0..15 of the first above that, such a description...

Comment: ...would suffice to describe the layout unambiguously on any platform regardless of its integer size or format.  Even if a platform used 18-bit `unsigned short` type, the indicated specification would direct the compiler to ignore the upper 2 bits of each unsigned short.  Reading and writing the value on such platforms would be much slower than on x86, but code could behave the same regardless.

Comment: @supercat So, something like `unsigned char foo[] = { struct.bar / 256, struct.bar % 256 };`, then?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: I'm not sure what syntax would be best, but perhaps `struct foo { unsigned short h,l; signed value : { l.0:16; h.0:16;} };`.  Rather than having to hope a compiler assigns bitfields in the proper sequence, code could say exactly where they need to go.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: Given such a declaration, `foo.value=65539;` would be equivalent to `foo.l = ((foo.l) & ~0xFFFF) | 3; foo.h = ((foo.h & ~0xFFFF) | 1;` regardless of the size of `unsigned short` (though of course if `unsigned short` happens to be 16 bits the expressions could be simplified a lot).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: It may also be practical to have a syntax expressly authorizing the compiler to do whatever it likes with certain bits of a structure member (or any bits beyond a certain point); such syntax could then allow the compiler to omit the masking steps when accessing `foo`.

Comment: @supercat Your bit fiddling interface makes no sense to me. What if you wanted to convert from two different source representations (e.g. big endian over the network, and little endian on the filesystem)? Additionally, what you're proposing isn't much less bulky than proper serialisation and deserialisation in C (e.g. my previous code, which is actual 100% compliant C).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: If the compiler could handle the array-ish syntax, a 32-bit big-endian value received as octets would be `struct foo { unsigned short b[4]; signed value : { b[3].0:8, b[2].0:8, b[1].0:8, b[0].0:8;} };`  Once the structure was defined, the syntax to access it would be compact, especially if there was a way of specifying that using the type as an integer lvalue should implicitly access member `value`.  Such a feature would mean that code which expects to be able to overlay a 32-bit big-endian `int32_t` on a sequence of `char` could instead overlay the aforementioned type.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: The advantages of this approach as I see it: (1) Platforms whose natural integer representation lined up with what was requested could optimize code to use that representation; (2) If the type could behave as an integer lvalue, existing non-portable code could easily be made portable merely by replacing certain usages of types like `uint32_t` with precise-layout types.

Comment: @supercat Or, you could just write a function that translates an array of two bytes to a 16-bit short value and use that everywhere! Hmmm, which is easier? Which uses less bytes? Which one **makes sense**? Compilers can optimise such code anyway. It's not a difficult task.

Comment: Further, while I agree that it's better to use functions than to rely upon type overlaying hacks when writing new code, there's a lot of existing code which uses pointer- and union-overlay hacks; refactoring such code to use packing and unpacking functions may be a clean approach, but being able to set up declarations in such a fashion that things can be made to "just work" (especially if a compiler can omit bit-packing steps for things whose address is never taken, and which are only accessed one way) could have considerable advantages as well.

Answer (score 2):

In 2's complement, all-bits-1 is the maximum negative value. So the sign-bit being `0` represents `0` and the sign-bit being `1` represents `-1`.

You're describing sign-magnitude representation in your question, in which case the representable values would indeed be `+0` and `-0`. But I'm not aware of any C++ implementation ever that did not use 2's complement.

Comment: Correct, and attempting to assign `1` to such a bitfield would produce undefined behaviour due to signed integer overflow anyway...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I would think that `bit = -1;` is legal (assuming 2's complement)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: No, it's not undefined behavior. `s.i = 1;` would *convert* the value `1` to the type of the bit-field, which can only represent the values `0` and `-1`. The conversion does not cause undefined behavior, it merely yields an implementation-defined result (or, starting with C99, it can raise an implementation-defined signal, but as far as I know no implementation actually does that).

Comment: @KeithThompson As mentioned in the other thread, there is still a chance that could cause undefined behaviour. Wouldn't it be nice to be able to merge these two series of comments?