# Are there any implementations that support a negative zero, or reserve it as a trap representation?

Tags: c, c99, c11

On most implementations of this day and age, a signed integer value that has a bit pattern of 1 for the sign bit and all 0 for the value bits tends to represent the lowest possible value for that signed integer type.

However, as [6.2.6.2p2](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p2) states, that's not a requirement:

> Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones' complement), is a trap representation or a normal value.

My first question is simple: Are there any implementations that use this bit pattern for a negative zero or a trap representation? If the answer to this question is 'no', then the answer to my follow-up questions must also be 'no'.

Following on from that question, [6.2.6.2p3](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p3) states that when a negative zero is assigned to an object, it might (or might not) be converted to a regular zero:

> It is unspecified whether these cases actually generate a negative zero or a normal zero, and whether a negative zero becomes a normal zero when stored in an object.

My follow-up questions:

1. Are there any implementations that use a trap representation rather than a negative zero for that bit pattern?
2. Are there any implementations that use a negative zero that is stored as a distinct value?
3. Are there any implementations that use a negative zero that is stored as a regular zero?

---

*edit for clarification: I am **NOT** asking for what is theoretically possible in a system that uses ones complement, twos complement or sign and magnitude representations for signed integers. I can find (and have found) that information in the sections I've cited from earlier in this question. I'm asking about **what has actually been done**.*

Comment: [One's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) has a distinct bit pattern for negative zero.

Comment: I believe UCS on OS 2200 (on Unisys Clearpath Dordado mainframes, which are one's complement machines) is a C implementation using one's complement, in which +ve and -ve zero are separate bit patterns.

Comment: @orlp Comments are meant for clarification, so I can only assume that you meant to phrase that in the form of a question. Wikipedia doesn't define C, and the first quote I gave (which *does* define at least part of C, since it comes from the C standard) states that that bit pattern might be a trap representation.

Comment: @IskarJarak An interesting implementation indeed that is! 18 bit integers... Hmmm.

Comment: @IskarJarak Interesting indeed, since it actually uses twos complement and in one mode, the value in question compares equal to zero in signed comparisons (but not unsigned comparisons) while in the other mode it's the highest possible value (which is technically non-conforming in C). If you're looking for a citation for an answer, [go to 2-29](https://public.support.unisys.com/2200/docs/cp13.2/pdf/78310430-015.pdf)... I'll leave it a few days for you to write up if you so wish, otherwise I'll write it up and give you credit for naming the implementation :)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Definitely a fairly unusual implementation, that's for sure. I'm not going to write an answer because I can't answer your follow-up Q1 re. trap representations (I don't know if any such implementation exists), so feel free to self-answer.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour No, I was just answering point 2 of your question in the comments :)

Comment: @IskarJarak I don't expect that anybody will be able to answer all of those questions... Someone might, and good for them; they'll get my favourite answer. It'd be nice for anyone else who comes to this question to be able to see at least a part of an answer, though.

Comment: @orlp If you're that confident, post it as an answer... You can do the same thing with all of the other questions, too. You could say... "1. Yes. An implementation that uses a trap representation rather than a negative zero is an implementation that uses a trap representation rather than a negative zero... 2. Yes, ones complement *might* store a negative zero as a distinct value... 3. Yes, ones complement *might* store a negative zero as a regular zero...". See how far not naming any *implementations* (which is what I asked for) gets us?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour There is no _might_. One's complement has two zeros: one positive and one negative. The all-zeros bit pattern is positive zero, the all-ones bit pattern is negative zero.

Comment: @orlp Can you show me a citation from the C standard, please?

Comment: @orlp I'll make it easy for you... You can find the section of the C standard that's relevant to signed integer representation above. I've linked to it twice in this question. Please don't respond until you have a citation (**from** the C standard, since nothing else is relevant here) backing up your claims, or are prepared to stop making disreputable and invalid assertions.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) has some examples of old, obscure systems. Maybe if you dig further into the specs of those systems...

Answer (score 2):

As brought to my attention by [Iskar Jarak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696485/iskar-jarak) within the comments, the OS2200, which was most recently released in February of 2015, has an implementation of C known as *UCS C*, of which [the manual](https://public.support.unisys.com/2200/docs/CP18.0/PDF/78310430-018.pdf) documents on page 2-29:

- a conforming C implementation where-by *"... CONFORMANCE/TWOSARITH is not used, negative zero is equivalent to zero in all 36-bit unsigned integer comparisons using less than (<), or equal (=). In unsigned comparisons using greater than (>), (2<sup>36</sup>)-1 is greater than zero."*
- a questionably-conforming C implementation where-by *"CONFORMANCE/TWOSARITH causes negative zero, (2<sup>36</sup>)-1, to be considered a large unsigned integer by the generated code."* As this violates several C standard clauses ([6.2.6.2p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p2) stating *"the sign bit has the value -(2<sup>M</sup>) (two's complement)"* and *"the sign bit has the value -(2<sup>M</sup>-1) (ones' complement)"*, [6.3.1.1p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p3) stating *"The integer promotions preserve value including sign"*, in contradiction to the conversion to *a large unsigned integer* specified within the UCS/OS2200 doc) it follows that this could only conform if the negative zero bit pattern is treated as a trap representation, where-by undefined behaviour is invoked and so the constraints of the standard no longer apply.

In summary, ...

> Are there any implementations that use this bit pattern for a negative zero or a trap representation?

Yes. The example provided can use this bit pattern for a negative zero *or* a trap representation, depending upon compiler conformance options.

---

For the follow-up questions 1&2, it follows that UCS C on OS2200 is an example of both of these.

As for question 3, to be answered another day... My time has come to end here :)

Comment: Does that implementation define an unsigned type with at least 64 bits?  The one's complement system I've looked at that appeared closest to conforming had an unsigned 36 bit type and a signed 72 bit type, but no unsigned 72-bit type.

Comment: @supercat Are we referring to the same implementation? If so, it appears from the documentation that this is a twos complement system with a trapping and/or non-conforming negative zero bit pattern. According to the docs linked to above (which claim "Latest programming language standards", heh heh), "Unsigned attribute is not allowed on long long integers", though it ought to be trivial for this implementation to implement `unsigned long long`... You're right; this appears to be a compliance issue.

Comment: Must be a different system (I was thinking of a 36-bit ones'-complement platform) but I suspect all conforming C99 platforms are for platforms with natural wrapping two's-complement semantics, since a 64-bit-or-larger unsigned type would be expensive on such a platform unless its word size was 65 bits or larger.

Comment: Would it be expensive to discard the sign bit (treat it as padding)? As it is, this implementation appears to do that by merging two `long`s to make a `long long`... "Expensive!" ;)

Comment: I don't know if that's what an implementation like the ones'-complement I read about, nor this one, actually do or if instead the upper half is scaled by (2^36-1) rather than (2^36).  If unsigned numbers weren't required to have a power-of-two modulus, one could efficiently perform long unsigned arithmetic mod (2^36-1)^2, but getting a power-of-two modulus would be much harder.  Note that even the documentation only promises a range of 2^70-1 for signed values, it might actually extend up to (2^36-1)(2^35)-1.

Comment: Use of operators like "&" on a number (H:L) in a not-quite-binary base would require turning it into into binary form; that would in turn require determining whether the H < L, H==L, or H > L.  The result would then be (H:L-H), (H-1:0xFFFFFFFFF), or (H-1:0xFFFFFFFFE-(H-L)+1).  Since binary operators would generally not be used very often on long signed types, incurring such costs when those operators are used would be far more reasonable than incurring them on all signed arithmetic operations.

Comment: Yeah, it's after you click the button that you get a 404.  Anyway I found the correct link and updated it.