# How can we guarantee that `fprintf(f, "%i", i)` will never result in an encoding error?

Tags: c, encoding, printf, runtime-error, language-lawyer

I think that we can guarantee that the call to `foo`,

```
int foo (FILE * f, int i)
{
    return fprintf(f, "%i", i);
}
```

will never produce an an encoding error if we can guarantee that `i` is not a trap representation (N2176, Representation of Types: General) because the characters `'-'`, `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'8'`, and `'9'` are found in the basic execution character set (N2176, Environmental Considerations: Character Sets), and these are all that are needed to represent the decimal form of any integral value that can be represented by an `int`. Also, the number of characters needed for the decimal representation of an `int` is guaranteed to be less than `INT_MAX` (so the return value of `fprintf` can always store the number of characters produced by the conversion).

So, the question reduces to:

How do we guarantee that an `int` does not store a trap representation?

(Or is it more complex?)

### It's more complex.

*This section has been added in response to the answers and comments (regarding* orientation *) thus far (2022-02-18).*

I think that we can guarantee that calls to `fputi` and / or `fwputi`,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int fputi ( int i , FILE * f )
{
    return fwide ( f , 0 ) <= 0
        ?  fprintf ( f ,  "%i" , i )
        : fwprintf ( f , L"%i" , i ) ;
}

// The only differences between fputi and fwputi should be:
// - their names and
// - the "<" or "<=" signs.

int fwputi ( int i , FILE * f )
{
    return fwide ( f , 0 ) < 0
        ?  fprintf ( f ,  "%i" , i )
        : fwprintf ( f , L"%i" , i ) ;
}
```

will never produce an an encoding error if we can guarantee that `i` is not a trap representation (N2176, Representation of Types: General) because the characters `'-'`, `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'8'`, and `'9'` are found in the basic execution character set (N2176, Environmental Considerations: Character Sets), and these are all that are needed to represent the decimal form of any integral value that can be represented by an `int`. Also, the number of characters needed for the decimal representation of an `int` is guaranteed to be less than `INT_MAX` (so the return value of `fprintf` or `fwprintf` can always store the number of characters produced by the conversion).

So, the question reduces to:

How do we guarantee that an `i` does not store a trap representation? *Or*, how do we modify `fputi` and `fwputi` so that they behave portably (i.e., consistently for all implementations that adhere to the Standard)? Maybe insert before the `return` statements:

```
// C-LIKE PSEUDO CODE
if ( isTrapRepresentation ( i ) ) exit ( EXIT_FAILURE ) ;
```

Comment: What is an "encoding error"?

Comment: @KamilCuk "An encoding error occurs if the character sequence presented to the underlying `mbrtowc` function does not form a valid (generalized) multibyte character, or if the code value passed to the underlying `wcrtomb` does not correspond to a valid (generalized) multibyte character" (N2176, Files; reformatted).

Comment: You would need to know what a trap representation looks like (if one exists at all) and check for it.

Comment: But it's `fprintf`. You never know what `fprintf` does behind the scenes, does it call anything, or not. So `How can we guarantee ...` we can contact the author of `fprintf` and make him release a statement. `will never produce an an encoding error if we can guarantee that i is not a trap representation` Why? Why would trap representation make `fprintf` cause an encoding error? Will it call `mbrtowc` then? How do you know? Also, `fgetwc` would call `mbrtowc`, why would `fprintf` call it?

Comment: Hmm, If the _orientation_ of `f` was established as wide before the `fprintf()` call, I'd expect an _encoding error_ is readily possible with this narrow call.  Review § 7.21.2 4

Comment: You cannot detect a trap representation in a portable way. You need to consult your compiler documentation.

Comment: @KamilCuk Re "Why would trap representation make `fprintf` cause an encoding error?" It seems to me that if `i` is a trap representation, anything could happen (undefined behavior), including the behavior that `fprintf` may report an encoding error if `i` is a trap value. Re "how do you know:" the point is that I don't know, which is why I want to eliminate that case.

Comment: My reasoning is, that it is irrelevant if it is a trap representation or not, because `fprintf` can generate encoding error whenever it wants to. While it is true that _when_ `i` is a trap representation, then anything could happen, but this is not a restriction. `fprintf` can generate encoding error unrelated to `i` being trap representation or not. You should contact the author of `fprintf` first and make him release a statement "when `i` is not a trap representation, then I guarantee that it will work".

Comment: @KamilCuk Re: "`fprintf` can generate [an] encoding error whenever it wants to." This is a sad surprise to me. Can you point me to some language in the Standard that support this?

Comment: I can't - it is not specified. Standard specifies behavior. There is no specification - "if inputs are valid, then there will be no errors" related to `fprintf`. That's my point that such specification does not exist.

Comment: It really is a question, are you asking from the perspective of a "language-lawyer" or practical? Because practically, there are no trap representation of `int` (everything is twos-complement) and you will get no encoding error except for wide/normal streams mix.

Comment: @KamilCuk Please clarify, is it a) "`fprintf` can generate encoding error whenever it wants to?" Or b) "you will get no encoding error" because 1) "everything is two-s complement" and 2) `fputi` and `fwputi` don't mix orientations?

Comment: I'd expect an encoding error, or _some error_  is possible in extreme cases like `frpintf(stream, "%s", s);` when `strlen(s) > INT_MAX`.  Yet since `fprintf()` already has environmental limits that were exceeded, that may fall under UB.  Of course `"%d"` will not make such an excessively long output.

Answer (score 2):

> I think that we can guarantee that the call to foo,... will never produce an an encoding error if we can guarantee that `i` is not a trap representation

Counter example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main() {
  int i = fwprintf(stdout, L"Hello world!\n");
  i = fwprintf(stdout, L"Step A %d\n", i);
  i = fwprintf(stdout, L"Step B %d\n", i);
  i = fprintf(stdout, "Step C %d\n", i);  // Returns -1
  fwprintf(stdout, L"Step D %d\n", i);
}
```

Output

```
Hello world!
Step A 13
Step B 10
Step D -1
```

Once a stream sets it *orientation* (print to wide or narrow characters), carelessly trying to print the other way results in an *encoding error*, even without a trap value in `i`.

---

> How can we guarantee that `fprintf(f, "%i", i)` will never result in an encoding error?

At a minimum, do not change orientation.

Comment: To compile without warnings, the example needs an `#include <wchar.h>`. Without this include there's an implicit declaration warning about `fwprintf()`.

Comment: @NathanMills Include added.

Comment: It seems to me that the original question may not have an answer, but +1 for helpfulness. I've edited the original post in attempt to move closer to something useful (to me).

Comment: Amazing! Blatant proof that wide characters should  be avoided completely.

Comment: @AnaNimbus [I've edited the original post in attempt to move closer to something useful (to me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71150512/how-can-we-guarantee-that-fprintff-i-i-will-never-result-in-an-encoding/71153214?noredirect=1#comment125815716_71153214) --> a moving target question reduces one's interest as not sure when/where it stops.   IMO, better to have posted another question.

Comment: @chqrlie IMO, time for `<u8.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

> How can we guarantee that `fprintf(f, "%i", i)` will never result in an encoding error?

We can contact the author of `fprintf`, distributor of our toolchain and/or compiler, or similar, and make that entity release a statement that it guarantees that `fprintf(f, "%i", i)` will not result in an encoding error.

> will never produce an an encoding error if we can guarantee that i is not a trap representation

This is based on a false premise. There is no such guarantee. `fprintf` may produce an encoding error, anytime, anywhere.

> How do we guarantee that an int does not store a trap representation?

We can create an array with all possible trap representations of a type. Then just check if the representation of `i` is one of the possible trap representations. For example:

```
static const unsigned char trap_representations_of_int[][sizeof(int)] = {
    // for example, on my imaginary architecture:
    // int has 3 bytes, architecture is big endian
    // and 0x00CAFE is a trap
    { 0x00, 0xCA, 0xFE, },
};
bool is_trap_representation_int(const int *num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LEN(trap_representations_of_int); ++i) {
        if (memcmp(num, trap_representations_of_int[i], sizeof(int)) == 0) {
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

`unsigned char` is guaranteed to not have a trap representation. You can inspect any data with it, also do ranges comparisons between bytes. The list of trap representation is something to be taken out from the architecture documentation.

---

On a practical note: there does not exist an architecture with `int` having any trap representations. I will leave that sentence here, until someone provides a counterexample, that would be fun to know.

And `fprintf` maybe will give you an encoding error when you mix wide/normal strings. When you use wide strings, you should be aware of [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107608/whats-wrong-with-c-wchar-t-and-wstrings-what-are-some-alternatives-to-wide), and you will work with the specific system you are targeting - it's specific to the environment anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586217/are-there-any-implementations-that-support-a-negative-zero-or-reserve-it-as-a-t sort of has an example of an `int` with a trap representation.  At least, an `int` value which behaves in a non-standard way, but could be comforming if that value is treated as a trap representation.  It's not clear if that implementation is generally conforming otherwise, though.

Comment: FYI: "there does not exist an architecture with int having any trap representations" --> An interesting read on some unusual, by todays' view, [machines](https://begriffs.com/posts/2018-11-15-c-portability.html).  Don't see any integer trap representations.